# "bad ecpoint" SSL error on fresh RVM Ruby 1.9.3 install on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion, ruby-1.9.3, rest-client

Trying to use Ruby 1.9.3 & `rest-client` to make https requests like:

```
RestClient.get('https://google.com')
```

always gives me a SSL error,

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server key exchange B: bad ecpoint
```

which I cannot figure out. `bad ecpoint`?

I've had no trouble making the same request with 1.9.3 & `rest-client` on another Mountain Lion machine.

Notes about this machine: MacBook pro with fresh Mountain Lion install, where I originally had some trouble installing gcc-4.2 via the XCode command line tools, but eventually got gcc-4.2 via [homebrew/dupes](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes). I've uninstalled & reinstalled RVM and 1.9.3 since then.

Comment: try: `rvm get head; rvm --autolibs=4 --debug requirements` - if it reports installing something then run `rvm reinstall 1.9.3`

Comment: thanks, trying this now. can you explain what this does? is it just updating rvm and checking if i have the requirements?

Comment: looks like i have plenty of problems here... will update once I understand what i was missing.

Comment: @mpapis fixed my problem, would you like the answer karma? else i will answer my own question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Explaining my comment...

Update RVM to latest development version (but `stable` should work too):

```
rvm get head
```

Install all required libraries for ruby (`autolibs=4` is for full automation):

```
rvm --autolibs=4 --debug requirements
```

Finally reinstall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

You can enable full library automation within RVM for next commands with:

```
rvm autolibs enable
```

Comment: excellent. Not sure why but my openssl install was hosed. I was missing a bunch of other dependencies as well. Thanks @mpapis.

Comment: A great explanation as well.