# Why do I get "bad ecpoint" with OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError Stripe transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I am building a Rails application with stripe integrated. I have everything setup except for when I try to carry out a transaction on my local development environment. I get:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server key exchange B: bad ecpoint
```

I tried a lot of different things to get a valid SSL cert on my machine but nothing seems to be working.

It isn't anything to do with my setup because it is working fine on a test heroku server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you list what version of Ruby and OpenSSL you have. Also, are you using RVM? I was able to get past this problem, but those pieces of info are required.

Comment: This also happened to me today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It typically happens when there are issues with the Ruby/OpenSSL integration. Try [updating RVM and reinstalling the libs/ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672133/bad-ecpoint-ssl-error-on-fresh-rvm-ruby-1-9-3-install-on-osx-mountain-lion).

If you're still having issues, please list the OS, Ruby, OpenSSL and rvm/rbenv versions you're using.

Comment: This fixed it. I removed all SSL certs and then removed rvm. reinstalled and made sure everything was up to date. Then updated the cert.