# Omniauth FB & Twitter resulting in SSL Errors (Faraday::SSLError & OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ssl, omniauth, faraday

I have a Rails 4 app running omniauth-facebook & omniauth-twitter, but all attempts to login are met with a Faraday::SSLError -- SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server key exchange B: bad ecpoint (for Facebook) and an OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError -- SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server key exchange B: bad ecpoint (for Twitter.)

I have tried to disable SSL Peer verification completely with the following, but to no avail:

config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
if Rails.env.development? 
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 
end
```

I've also tried a bunch of root certificate solutions, such as:

```
sudo port install curl-ca-bundle
```

but to no avail.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://ga.be/blog/2013/10/02/fixing-rubygems-ssl-issues-certificate-verify-failed/

The above link might help you just have a look.
It is just the error of SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the solution is to search for the "bad ecpoint" error message. These search results point to an integration problem between Ruby und OpenSSL and will show you how to resolve the issue:

- [Why do I get "bad ecpoint" with OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError Stripe transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158104/why-do-i-get-bad-ecpoint-with-opensslsslsslerror-stripe-transaction)
- ["bad ecpoint" SSL error on fresh RVM Ruby 1.9.3 install on OSX Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672133/bad-ecpoint-ssl-error-on-fresh-rvm-ruby-1-9-3-install-on-osx-mountain-lion)