# `rhc setup` error: `A secure connection could not be established to the server`

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I cannot get past the following error:

```
$ rhc setup
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace,
and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.

A secure connection could not be established to the server (SSL_connect
returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server key exchange B: bad ecpoint). You may
disable secure connections to your server with the -k (or --insecure) option
'https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api'.

If your server is using a self-signed certificate, you may disable certificate
checks with the -k (or --insecure) option. Using this option means that your
data is potentially visible to third parties.
```

I have run `rhc setup -k` (to the same end) as well as `sudo gem update rhc` (I have the latest versions of everything, AFAIK). I've also deleted the `~/.openshift` directory to no avail. My ssh keys seem fine and intact otherwise, but maybe are corrupted somehow?

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently doing maintenance and upgrading openshift online (https://openshift.redhat.com/app/status) please try again or try waiting until the maintenance is done.  It is also possible that you are on a network that is using a proxy, or proxying https requests with it's own certificate.

This fix (["bad ecpoint" SSL error on fresh RVM Ruby 1.9.3 install on OSX Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672133/bad-ecpoint-ssl-error-on-fresh-rvm-ruby-1-9-3-install-on-osx-mountain-lion)) ultimately solved the users issue.

Comment: I have been trying as of 4 days ago so I think it might not be the maintenance. I'll look into the proxies-- any idea how I could confirm if they are indeed interfering?

Comment: Can you load that url into your browser and see what happens? https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api  Also, are you running this from your computer, or a server somewhere?

Comment: My local computer, which previously could run `rhc` no problem on the same network (which has remained unaltered AFAIK). Loading that URL in Chrome gives me a blank white page, headers say response code `406`

Comment: What operating system are you using? And are you using rvm/rbenv?  Also try loading this url in your browser: https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api.json

Comment: The json link works as expected (`status: "ok"`), and I'm on Mac OSX 10.9.2. I have rvm installed and updated.

Comment: One of our engineers suggested this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672133/bad-ecpoint-ssl-error-on-fresh-rvm-ruby-1-9-3-install-on-osx-mountain-lion

Answer (score 9):

Your rhc gem may be out of date. I fixed this problem by typing at the command line:

```
gem install rhc
```

Then I was able to go through the setup procedure (again).

Answer (score 3):

You can also add  **ssl_version=tlsv1** to **.openshift/express.conf** in order to set a non SSLv3 protocol as described in this [link](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1233863)

That worked for me.

Edit:
I've find out that you can also resolve this with a `sudo gem update rhc`  from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514402/receiving-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-hello-a-sslv3?rq=1) question

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
unset http_proxy
```

and then running rhc setup again.
or define no_proxy:

```
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1, example.com"
```