# Receiving "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure" with openshift nodejs app

Tags: node.js, ssl, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have a nodejs app on openshift, and we use the rhc port-forward command to connect to our database when we develop locally.

We have implemented passport to authenticate users through google and through facebook. I have authenticated my self, and we could still use the rhc commands. My partner has recently authenticated himself through facebook, and shortly after that (~1 week), we got this error thrown our way. Dont know if that is entirely relevant, but it couldn't hurt to include.

```
Connection to openshift.redhat.com failed: A secure connection could not be established to the   server
(SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure). You may
disable secure connections to your server with the -k (or --insecure) option
'https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api'.

If your server is using a self-signed certificate, you may disable certificate checks with the -k (or
--insecure) option. Using this option means that your data is potentially visible to third parties.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I have seen this error on other stack questions, but every question I saw, the people posing the question were using ruby.

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with POODLE and the disabling of SSLv3 on the server-side. You might try forcing TLS 1.x when connecting to the server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is likely a result of the POODLE SSLv3 debacle. You can fix it by updating the httpclient ruby gem. At the command line type:

```
sudo gem update httpclient
```

Or you can also fix it by adding the following to your .openshift/express.conf file:

```
ssl_version=tlsv1
```

Both of these fixes essentially tell your app to use TLSv1 instead of SSLv3.

Comment: "sudo gem install httpclient" is not work for me. I got "An unexpected error occured: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" instead. "gem update rhc" fixed.

Comment: This did not work for me, either, but `gem update rhc` did (see my comment to the answer below). It updated `rhc`, and also updated `httpclient` to `httpclient-2.5.3.3`. Did you mean `update` instead of `install`, or are the cases where `install` will suffice?

Comment: @JohnSchmidt, install works if you are using a new gemset or something but most of all I believe update should be used. You could also use install with the -v option if you don't want to update to the latest version but to a specific version you know will work.

Comment: My answer worked for me but it looks like the answer below using "gem update rhc" was more widely useful so although this is ancient and not a problem anymore I'd recommend that answer first probably

Answer (score 7):

The rhc gem has been updated, please run `gem update rhc` and you will get the newest fixed version.

Comment: This also worked for me, beautifully. `update` worked where every iteration of `install`, or `uninstall` followed by `install`, etc. failed. It updated `rhc` to `rhc-1.32.2` and `httpclient` to `httpclient-2.5.3.3`. So where `install` doesn't work, try `update`. I don't know enough about the **rubygems** system to know why `update` would succeed when a fresh install doesn't, but that was my experience, in this instance at least.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows with ruby 1.9.3 and httpclient 2.3.4.1

`gem update httpclient` updated the same to 2.5.3.3 and thus fixed the issue.