# how to post to ssl from rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi all i'm trying to post the following from a controller in rails, however I constantly get the following error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert handshake failur
```

am I doing something wrong?

```
uri = URI.parse('https://devcheckout.psigate.com/HTMLPost/HTMLMessenger')

form_data = { 'StoreKey' => 'psigatecapturescard001010',
             'CustomerRefNo' => 'Monday Evening Muay Thai Classes',
             'UserID' => 'jsmith',
             'SubTotal' => '34.00'
            }

response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, form_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this, the accepted answer could maybe solve your problem:

[Using Net::HTTP.get for an https url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786779/using-nethttp-get-for-an-https-url)

also here are some informations about the error returned:

[Receiving "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert handshake failure" with openshift nodejs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514402/receiving-ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-hello-a-sslv3)

The errors seems to occur because your Net::HTTP instance use a SSL version (SSLv3) not supported by your server.

Try setting the ssl_version to 'TLSv1'

```
uri = URI.parse('https://devcheckout.psigate.com/HTMLPost/HTMLMessenger')

form_data = { 'StoreKey' => 'psigatecapturescard001010','CustomerRefNo' => 'Monday Evening Muay Thai Classes','UserID' => 'jsmith', 'SubTotal' => '34.00'}


http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # read into this
@data = http.post(uri.request_uri, form_data.to_query)
```

tried it, works perfectly fine

Comment: i'm getting the following error wit hthe uri.query_values:

undefined method `query_values=' for #<URI::HTTPS:0x007f2bbc1b83e0>.  Does the URI class have this method?

Comment: my mistake, left over code from trrying, remove this line :-) it should be form_data = ...
i corrected it above

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
uri = URI('https://devcheckout.psigate.com/HTMLPost/HTMLMessenger')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
req.set_form_data(
                  'StoreKey' => 'psigatecapturescard001010',
                  'CustomerRefNo' => 'Monday Evening Muay Thai Classes',
                  'UserID' => 'jsmith',
                  'SubTotal' => '34.00'
                  )

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
```

Comment: produces 'NoMethodError: undefined method `use_ssl=' for #<Net::HTTP::Post POST>', also does not solve the real issue: request uses SSLv3, which is old, instead TLSv1 should be used, as pointed out in my answer below